# Python. Классы и объекты

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Дали задание по программированию для самостоятельного выполнения, тему слабовато понял, поэтому прошу помощи у вас, желательно с объяснением:

Создайте класс `Car`, который имеет атрибуты `make` (марка автомобиля), `model` (модель автомобиля) и `year` (год выпуска). Дайте им также метод `display_info()`, который выводит информацию о машине (марка, модель и год).

Comment: спасибо, что поделились! удачи в выполнении задания!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, brand, model, year):
        self.brand = brand
        self.model = model
        self.year = year

    def display_info(self):
        print(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return f""" Автомобиль:
    Марка: {self.brand}
    Модель: {self.model}
    Год: {self.year}"""


def main():
    car = Car("BMW", "740", "2004")
    car.display_info() # Магия :-)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Оказали медвежью услугу студенту, зачем? Понятно, что конец декабря и лабы горят, но так он ничему не научится...

Comment: Да ладно, просто делать нечего было, кстати напечатал прям здесь) На телефоне с маленьким экраном, несколько раз хотел закрыть и бросить))) Всё равно препод не поверит что он сам это сделал)))

Comment: Ну если сможет рассказать, что происходит в этом коде, то, может, и поверит :)